# Amzi Prolog won't pass value when being called

Tags: prolog, amzi-prolog

```
/* MAIN PROGRAM */

main:- welcome.

welcome:-
    write('************************************************'),nl,
    write('*   Welcome to my Simple Calculator   *'),nl,
    write('************************************************'),nl,nl,
    write('For every input you enter, please followed by a full stop[.]'),
    numbers.

numbers:-
    nl,nl,write('First number: '),
    read(FIRST),nl,
    write('Second number: '),
    read(SECOND),nl,
    operation.

operation:-
    nl,write('[1]- Addition.'), nl,
    nl,write('[2]- Subtraction.'),nl,
    nl,write('[3]- Multiplication.'),nl,
    nl,write('[4]- Division.'),nl,
    nl,write('[5]- Exit.'),nl,
    nl,write(':>'),
    read(ANS1),nl,
    set_op(ANS1).

set_op(1):-
    write(FIRST),write(SECOND),
    SUM is FIRST + SECOND,
    write(SUM).
```

I'm having trouble doing a simple calculator program. For some reason, it will only pass the address of the variable instead of the value when being called. I appreciate if someone could point my slip. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in Prolog are *not global*. So the `FIRST` and `SECOND` in your `set_op` are *locally scoped*. So the `FIRST` and `SECOND` in your `set_op/1` are different variables than the ones in your `numbers/0` predicate.

In a declarative programming languages, normally the result of a function/predicate/… depends only on the parameters passed. Although in Prolog there are some ways to represent a "global state" like a non-backtrackable store, it is often seen as better to apply that principle, and thus not implement some sort of global state.

You need to pass variables, like:

```
numbers :-
    nl,nl,write('First number: '),
    read(First),nl,
    write('Second number: '),
    read(Second),nl,
    operation(First, Second).

operation(First, Second) :-
    nl,write('[1]- Addition.'), nl,
    nl,write('[2]- Subtraction.'),nl,
    nl,write('[3]- Multiplication.'),nl,
    nl,write('[4]- Division.'),nl,
    nl,write('[5]- Exit.'),nl,
    nl,write(':>'),
    read(Op),nl,
    write(First), write(Second),
    set_op(Op, First, Second).

set_op(1, First, Second) :-
    Sum is First + Second,
    write(Sum).
```

Comment: Well, today i learned! I totally have no idea that's how they implement global and local.
Thanks so much friend, i appreciate it so much!